# Laravel Media Library error in generated_conversions

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb, migration

I received an error rooting from [Media Library](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary) package.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'generated_conversions' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `media` (...
```

After research, I found out that 6 days ago there was an upgrade from From v8 to v9 which asks to add a JSON column generated_conversions to the media table.

Here is the migration file that was suggested

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media;

class AddGeneratedConversionsToMediaTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        if ( ! Schema::hasColumn( 'media', 'generated_conversions' ) ) {
            Schema::table( 'media', function ( Blueprint $table ) {
                $table->json( 'generated_conversions' );
            });
        }
        
        Media::query()
            ->whereNull('generated_conversions')
            ->orWhere('generated_conversions', '')
            ->orWhereRaw("JSON_TYPE(generated_conversions) = 'NULL'")
            ->update([
                'generated_conversions' => DB::raw('custom_properties->"$.generated_conversions"'),
            // OPTIONAL: Remove the generated conversions from the custom_properties field as well:
            // 'custom_properties'     => DB::raw("JSON_REMOVE(custom_properties, '$.generated_conversions')")
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        /* Restore the 'generated_conversions' field in the 'custom_properties' column if you removed them in this migration
        Media::query()
            ->whereRaw("JSON_TYPE(generated_conversions) != 'NULL'")
            ->update([
                'custom_properties' => DB::raw("JSON_SET(custom_properties, '$.generated_conversions', generated_conversions)")
            ]);
        */
    
        Schema::table( 'media', function ( Blueprint $table ) {
            $table->dropColumn( 'generated_conversions' );
        });
    }
}
```

But when I ran `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` I get an error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '>"$.generated_conversions", `media`.`updated_at` = ? where `generated_conversion' at line 1 (SQL: update `media` set `generated_conversions` = custom_properties->"$.generated_conversions", `media`.`updated_at` = 2021-04-17 20:22:02 where `generated_conversions` is null or `generated_conversions` =  or JSON_TYPE(generated_conversions) = 'NULL')
```

Does anyone know the issue with the file? Thank you

Comment: which version of mariadb are you using?

Comment: first we use MYSQL. and its version 8 (the latest for enterprise)

Comment: Bump,  same issue ^ any help or resolution?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to follow the upgrade guide from https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/blob/main/UPGRADING.md

````
## From v8 to v9

- add a `json` column `generated_conversions` to the `media` table (take a look at the default migration for the exact definition). You should copy the values you now have in the `generated_conversions` key of the `custom_properties` column to `generated_conversions`
- You can create this migration by running `php artisan make:migration AddGeneratedConversionsToMediaTable`.
- Here is the content that should be in the migration file
```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media;

class AddGeneratedConversionsToMediaTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        if ( ! Schema::hasColumn( 'media', 'generated_conversions' ) ) {
            Schema::table( 'media', function ( Blueprint $table ) {
                $table->json( 'generated_conversions' );
            } );
        }
        
        Media::query()
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->whereNull('generated_conversions')
                    ->orWhere('generated_conversions', '')
                    ->orWhereRaw("JSON_TYPE(generated_conversions) = 'NULL'");
            })
            ->whereRaw("JSON_LENGTH(custom_properties) > 0")
            ->update([
                'generated_conversions' => DB::raw('custom_properties->"$.generated_conversions"'),
                // OPTIONAL: Remove the generated conversions from the custom_properties field as well:
                // 'custom_properties'     => DB::raw("JSON_REMOVE(custom_properties, '$.generated_conversions')")
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        /* Restore the 'generated_conversions' field in the 'custom_properties' column if you removed them in this migration
        Media::query()
                ->whereRaw("JSON_TYPE(generated_conversions) != 'NULL'")
                ->update([
                    'custom_properties' => DB::raw("JSON_SET(custom_properties, '$.generated_conversions', generated_conversions)")
                ]);
        */
    
        Schema::table( 'media', function ( Blueprint $table ) {
            $table->dropColumn( 'generated_conversions' );
        } );
    }
}
````

- rename `conversion_file_namer` key in the `media-library` config to `file_namer`. This will support both the conversions and responsive images from now on. More info [in our docs](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v9/advanced-usage/naming-generated-files).
- You will also need to change the value of this configuration key as the previous class was removed, the new default value is `Spatie\MediaLibrary\Support\FileNamer\DefaultFileNamer::class`
- in several releases of v8 config options were added. We recommend going over your config file in `config/media-library.php` and add any options that are present in the default config file that ships with this package.

Comment: thank you very much. i do it and problem solved. thank you after that want me to enable extensions: 1-gd 2-mbstring 3-exif then all worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the migration code as below for MariaDB.

Please refer here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-column-path for the explanations.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media;

class AddGeneratedConversionsToMediaTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
        if ( ! Schema::hasColumn( 'media', 'generated_conversions' ) ) {
            Schema::table( 'media', function ( Blueprint $table ) {
                $table->json( 'generated_conversions' )->nullable();
            } );
        }
        
        Media::query()
            ->where(function ($query) {
                $query->whereNull('generated_conversions')
                    ->orWhere('generated_conversions', '')
                    ->orWhereRaw("JSON_TYPE(generated_conversions) = 'NULL'");
            })
            ->whereRaw("JSON_LENGTH(custom_properties) > 0")
            ->update([
                //'generated_conversions' => DB::raw('custom_properties->"$.generated_conversions"'),
                'generated_conversions' => DB::raw("JSON_EXTRACT(custom_properties, '$.generated_conversions')"),
                // OPTIONAL: Remove the generated conversions from the custom_properties field as well:
                // 'custom_properties'     => DB::raw("JSON_REMOVE(custom_properties, '$.generated_conversions')")
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
        /* Restore the 'generated_conversions' field in the 'custom_properties' column if you removed them in this migration
        Media::query()
                ->whereRaw("JSON_TYPE(generated_conversions) != 'NULL'")
                ->update([
                    'custom_properties' => DB::raw("JSON_SET(custom_properties, '$.generated_conversions', generated_conversions)")
                ]);
        */
    
        Schema::table( 'media', function ( Blueprint $table ) {
            $table->dropColumn( 'generated_conversions' );
        } );
    }
}
```